# Two images do not perfect align when using Pillow putalpha to set image transparency

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, png

I am learning to use Pillow library to process images, and I am following this tutorial (https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-putalpha/) to use the `putalpha()` method. I was able to use the `horse.png` and `horse_r.png` to set different parts of the image to be transparent. However, I found that when I put these two images together in a Microsoft Word or Powerpoint document or in PhotoShop, one above another, there always displays a white line contour of the horse. I checked the value of pixels of both images at the coordinate where the white line appears, which all seem correct, there is not any pixel whose alpha is set as 0 on both images. I wonder where this white line comes from and how to make it disappear?

Here are the two images for the code:

[image]
[image]

And here is the code I have used to generate the two images:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter, ImageOps

im_check = Image.open('horse.png').convert('1')
im_check.save('horse.png')
im_check_r = ImageOps.invert(im_check)
im_check_r.save('horse_r.png')

im_rgb = Image.open('lena.jpg')
im_a = Image.open('horse.png').convert('1').resize(im_rgb.size)
im_rgba = im_rgb.copy()
im_rgba.putalpha(im_a)
im_rgba.save('1.png')

im_a = Image.open('horse_r.png').convert('1').resize(im_rgb.size)
im_rgba = im_rgb.copy()
im_rgba.putalpha(im_a)
im_rgba.save('2.png')
```

[image: The first picture setting the horse part transparent.]
[image: The second picture setting the reverse-horse part transparent.]
[image: When I place one picture above another.]

Comment: I'm not sure Microsoft Word should be the final judge of any image processing! Presumably you have an input image of a horse and Lena, and some code and an output image (not created by Microsoft) so those belong in your [mcve] question please.

Comment: Thanks I have updated my question to add my code!

Comment: Please add `"horse.png"` and `"lena.jpg"` to your question so we can use the exact same images.

Answer (score 0):

Try compositing your saved images, `p2.png` over `p1.png` like this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Open your saved images
p1 = Image.open('1.png')
p2 = Image.open('2.png')

# Composite p2.png over p1.png
composite = Image.alpha_composite(p1, p2)

# Save result
composite.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, my question is more leaning to the "why" side, because I can just use the original image rather than split and then composite them together. What is the reason this white line exist, is there something I did incorrectly to use the putalpha function?

Comment: I only took your results and composited them properly - I have no idea why Microsoft can't do that. In general, it would be better to resize **first** then change to bi-level (mode=1) **afterwards** then you round a more accurate result rather than moving to a bi-level mode and then rounding. You could try in this order... `Image.open().resize().convert()`